# Decipher electrical junction

Tags: wiring

I am replacing an light fixture and box. The box is not actually a box, it's a round thing with 4 round tubular portals. The electricians have treated this thing as a junction box so it has a lot of wires I want to decipher the purpose of. There are two lines of Greenfield going into the box and two lines of Romex going into it. In the diagram below I have labeled the Greenfield lines A and B, and the Romex lines X and Y.

[image]

My plan is to add a junction box and have the connections in the box. Then add a second box for the light to which only two wires will go (doh).

Should I keep this same wiring scheme or change it?

Comment: A picture would help. Read it twice, but I still don't follow.

Comment: I agree with Tyson the greenfield and Romex are supply to other things change the wiring and something or nothing may work some things may be a switch loop some ? But your diagram makes no sense to me what colors are the wires xb, ab, a2, b2

Comment: @EdBeal The light fixture has two wires, white and black. The Black wire coming from the light fixture is connected to A1, B1 and XW. The White wire coming from the fixture is connected to YW (the white wire from Romex cable Y). One wire from both A and B is connected to the black wires from X and Y. (Greenfield does not have colored wires)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe this is a switch loop with the supply going to the box. I think Xb, Yb, A2, B2 is the hot supply leg and going to additional lighting or some outlets. Xw, A1 B1 and to the light is the neutral. Yw is the return from the switch (romex Y caries hot to the switch and the white returns the hot to the light when turned on. If this matches what you have the light fixture is wired backwards  and the Yw wire should be marked with tape, marker or paint (I like red for a switched leg but black is normal).

Comment: Yes, that confirms my estimate as well and also is consistent with the readings from the voltage tester. In that case it would seem that the only corrective action necessary is to switch the wires in the new fixture so that the BLACK lighting wire goes to YW and the WHITE lighting wire goes to the 4-way junction with A1, B1 and XW. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes Yw should be the light's black wire and the light's white wire to XW, A1,B1.  Also a piece of black tape on the XW white wire so it is identified as a Hot.